# How to configure tensorflow with CPU support?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, cpu

I am trying to run tensorflow with CPU support.

tensorflow:
Version: 1.14.0

Keras:
Version: 2.3.1

When I try to run the following piece of code :

```py
def run_test_harness(trainX,trainY,testX,testY):
    datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.0)
    train_it = datagen.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=1)
    test_it = datagen.flow(testX, testY, batch_size=1)
    model=define_model()

    history = model.fit_generator(train_it, steps_per_epoch=len(train_it),
        validation_data=test_it, validation_steps=len(test_it), epochs=1, verbose=0)
```

I get the following error as shown in image:

[Image shows the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXJOG.jpg)

I tried to configure bazel for the same but it was of no use. It would be helpful if someone could direct me to resources or help with the problem. Thank you

**EDIT :** (Warning messages)

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/neha/valiance/kerascpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:4070: The name tf.nn.max_pool is deprecated. Please use tf.nn.max_pool2d instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/neha/valiance/kerascpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py:180: add_dispatch_support.<locals>.wrapper (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
2020-10-22 12:41:36.023849: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-10-22 12:41:36.326420: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2299965000 Hz
2020-10-22 12:41:36.327496: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x5502350 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2020-10-22 12:41:36.327602: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2020-10-22 12:41:36.679930: W tensorflow/compiler/jit/mark_for_compilation_pass.cc:1412] (One-time warning): Not using XLA:CPU for cluster because envvar TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit was not set.  If you want XLA:CPU, either set that envvar, or use experimental_jit_scope to enable XLA:CPU.  To confirm that XLA is active, pass --vmodule=xla_compilation_cache=1 (as a proper command-line flag, not via TF_XLA_FLAGS) or set the envvar XLA_FLAGS=--xla_hlo_profile.
2020-10-22 12:41:36.890241: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:107] Allocation of 3406823424 exceeds 10% of system memory.
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 python3 model.py
```

Comment: Hey! Please post your error message as text. The image you shared is not really readable. You should also fix the indentation in the code snippet you shared.

Comment: Unfortunately my system hangs everytime I run this code and I have to force shut down it. So I have not been able to copy the text. Could you try double clicking the image as it becomes clear then? Also I'll fix the indentation/

Comment: These are not error messages, it is likely that the problem is that you do not have enough RAM for the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try running your code on google colab. I think there aren't enough resources available on your PC for the task you are trying to run even though you are using a batch_size of 1.

Comment: @NehaJain I see you are working with .tif data for satellite imagery. I recently built a classifier on it but I extracted ndvi values to a csv file form the .tif rather than using the image to build a classifier. Head over to link for any help : [link](https://github.com/Akhilesh64/Land-Cover-Classification)

Comment: I want to classify copper mines.. Would NDVI values help?

Comment: NDVI values work well for distinguishing vegetation cover among other things. Can you provide me with a sample tif file contating copper mines ? I would like to see if ndvi values would be of help to you or not.